# Devata puja/homas during Pitru Paksha

Tags: puja, pitru, homam

During Pitru Paksha new ceremonies, like gruha pravesha, Upanayana, wedding, etc. are not allowed.

But is it ok for one to perform special (something more than daily puja) devata pujas/homas (for example Satyanarayana Puja, Gana homa) during this period at home or at temple?

If it can be done, what are the priorities with respect to Shraddha rituals (what conflicts to be considered, which one is done first)?

Comment: If not from scriptures, comments based on learned individuals/brahmanas, local customs also welcome.

Comment: Pitri paksha occurs in the dark fortnight, & it is unadvisable to conduct special worship the devas in the dark fortnight, for it has been reserved for pitris. Specific exceptions are applicable in case of naimittika karma & in cases of emergency.